# Normalize x-axis of time series

Tags: matlab

I have :

```
x=randn(1,100);
plot(x)
```

I want to normalize x-axis. Loads of methods are available to normalize magnitude/y-axis but normalization of x-axis is what I want to do. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x=randn(1,100);
plot(linspace(0,1, length(x)), x);
```

Comment: It still didn't normalize the x-axis. Here plot(x) is between 0 and 100 while I want it to be between 0 and 1.

Comment: Try `plot(linspace(0,1, length(x)), x);`

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: I guess if you update your answer with the above, you will get your answer accepted... As opposed to the current answer, your comment answers the question perfectly. =)

Comment: @RobertP. ok let's do it!

Comment: X-axis is normalized but please tell how to "use" the elements of normalized x-axis.

Comment: What do you mean by use?

Comment: This normalization occurs in plot but what if I want to perform any operation on the index of this normalized x-axis?